# How to override values from value.yaml file into value.dev.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have some Helm value files.

There are `value.yaml`, `value.dev.yaml`, `value.test.yaml`, ... file.

In `value.dev.yaml`:

```
env:
  "Environment"  "development"
```

For some parameters in `value.yaml` file, I expected they override or insert them into pod parameters while deployment.

If I set up them into each `value.dev.yaml`, `value.test.yaml`,... it works with `helm upgrade --install --set env.parameter=$variable`

Now I want to define all variables in `value.yaml` file and expect them insert (override) them in to pods while deployment.

In `value.yaml` file :

```
env:
  "Appconfig": "dev"
```

I'd like to combine them while deployment:

```
env:
  "Environment": "development"
  "Appconfig": "dev"
```

Apreciate your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `--values`/`-f` flag multiple times. The priority will be given to the **last** (right-most) file specified. For example, if both `myvalues.yaml` and `override.yaml` contained a key called 'Test', the value set in `override.yaml` would take precedence:

```
$ helm install -f myvalues.yaml -f override.yaml  myredis ./redis
```

- Ref [Helm Install Doc](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/)

Comment: so we can `$ helm install -f values.dev.yaml -f value.yaml myredis ./redis --set env.parameter=$variable`

Comment: yes, all three will be applied in their order.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to apply `-f values.yaml` explicitly. Helm applies the default values file automatically. You use `-f` or `--set` to override the values in default `values.yaml` file.

Comment: I meant I have a child file is `vaule.dev.yaml` and some variable from parent file `value.yaml` need to be INSERTED into pods variable while deployment

Comment: theoretically, `values.yaml` should be the superset of `vaule.dev.yaml`, shouldn't it? By doing `-f values.dev.yaml -f value.yaml`, you are actually doing `-f values.yaml`, `vaule.dev.yaml`  doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Can you take a look, just updated the question